# Аутентификация на веб-сервисе из Android-приложения по SSL

Tags: android, ssl, аутентификация, веб-служба, tls

Есть REST веб-сервис, развернутый на сервере с установленным сертификатом SSL, с одной стороны.

Есть приложение под Android, работающее с этим сервисом, с другой стороны.

Для доступа к веб-сервису необходимо сначала пройти процедуру аутентификации и передать ему логин и пароль.

Вопросы:

1. Как передать свои данные на сервер зашифрованными через защищенный протокол SSL, а не просто в теле HTTP-запроса??
2. Достаточно ли отправить запрос к веб-сервису по протоколу HTTPS, чтобы он был зашифрован и передан в зашифрованном виде??
3. При входе на защищенный SSL-сертификатом сайт через браузер, браузер отвечает за предоставление клиентского сертификата или проверку сертификата сервера. Как эта процедура происходит при обращении к защищенному веб-сервису из пользовательского Android-приложения (не браузер)??
4. Сколько статей про SSL уже перечитал, так и не могу понять, как же происходит отправка запроса по SSL. Объясните на пальцах бестолковому, как и в каком виде отправляется HTTP-запрос по SSL в Android-приложении??

Comment: Или, другими словами, "что такое HTTPS и почему его достаточно?"

Comment: @D-side Другими словами: "принцип работы SSL". Как из Android-приложения установить безопасное соединение с REST веб-службой??